# Error returning a json from php to reactjs with axios

Tags: php, json, reactjs, axios

The current code is being worked reactjs and executing the ajax request with axios with version 0.14.2:

```
    componentWillMount(){

    const peticion = this;
    const config = { 
                        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                        transformRequest: [function (data) { return data; }],
                        transformResponse: [function (data) { return data; }],
                        //responseType: 'json'
                    };

    axios.get('procesos/lista.php', config)
    .then( function (r){

        console.log(r);

        peticion.setState({
            datos:[r.data] | []
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I is returning plain text, as I can fix it.

The text and not returning it is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the problem was to work with webpack and let it run continuously, what I did was ejeuctar in webpack webpack.config.js console and generate bundle.js and ready  axios works perfect and also requests $ .ajax.